# Windows Server 2012 R2 NFS identity mapping linux client

Tags: linux, windows, server, identity, passwd

I'm trying to identity map a Ubuntu 12.04 machine to a NFS share on a Windows 2012 R2 machine.

I have a limited amount of Ubuntu machines, all with the same user.

[This:](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2012/10/09/nfs-identity-mapping-in-windows-server-2012.aspx)

States that I can identity map if I create a `passwd` and `group` file under:

```
System32/drivers/etc
```

I did so with `passwd` as follows:

```
localhost\user:x:1000:1000
```

group:

```
localhost\UNIXuser:x:1:user
```

On the Windows machine I created the UNIXuser group with the user being a member.

The windows event viewer (`ServicesForNFS-Server\IdentitiyMapping`) says:

```
A syntax error was found on line 1 when loading C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\passwd. The file will not be used as a mapping source.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\group will be used as a mapping source.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) On Windows NFS client, create local user `<Unix_user>`

2) Edit C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\passwd
`<localhost>\<Unix_user>:x:<Unix_UID>:<Unix_GID>:User Description,,,:c:\users\<Unix_user>`

3) Edit C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\group
`<localhost>\<Unix_group>:x:<Unix_GID>:<Unix_UID>`

Comment: Thanks for the clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The `passwd` file syntax is as follows:

`<localhost>\<user>:x:UID:GID:windows user description,,,:c:\users\<user>`